impure function inside a DO CONCURRENT block
Impure functions are not allowed to be used inside DO CONCURRENT blocks:
  ! Not allowed
  do concurrent(i=0:10)
    y(i) = impure_func(i)
  end do

But gfortran (v12.2.0) allows this if the impure function is inside a BLOCK inside the DO CONCURRENT block:
  ! Allowed
  do concurrent(i=0:10)
    block
      y(i) = impure_func(i)
    end block
  end do

What I want to know is that

Why is this allowed? Is this a bug for is it a feature?
If it is not a gfortran bug, how are the side-effects of using an impure function inside a DO CONCURRENT block avoided. Does gfortran prevent parallelizations of such a block?


A compiler must be capable of reporting that you've referenced an impure procedure, that doesn't mean that it must. But in this case, one would imagine "bug" to be suitable, but being kind to the compiler writers because you go out of your way to make detection harder.

If you'd like people to explore the exact behaviour of gfortran for you, please make complete example ([mre]).

Using a block inside a do concurrent is not an uncommon practice. Although in the given example is unnecessary. We do that to define local variables.

I don't call blocks uncommon, inside other constructs or otherwise. You know that impure function references aren't allowed inside DO CONCURRENT and have found a case where a compiler doesn't complain. I'm suggesting why the compiler may find it harder to diagnose your violation, rather than saying there is no violation.

I actually found this by accident. I was cleaning up a code and I thought this block isn't needed any more. The decision to make that function impure was taken a few years ago because of another gfortran bug. The workaround included a pointer assignment.

Unreported bugs typically go unfixed.
diff --git a/gcc/fortran/resolve.cc b/gcc/fortran/resolve.cc
index b8c908b51e9..1b98be205b4 100644
--- a/gcc/fortran/resolve.cc
+++ b/gcc/fortran/resolve.cc
@@ -3228,6 +3228,24 @@ pure_stmt_function (gfc_expr *e, gfc_symbol *sym)
 static bool check_pure_function (gfc_expr *e)
 {
   const char *name = NULL;
+  code_stack *stack;
+  bool saw_block = false;
+  
+  /* A BLOCK construct within a DO CONCURRENT construct leads to 
+     gfc_do_concurrent_flag = 0 when the check for an impure function
+     occurs.  Check the stack to see if the source code has a nested
+     BLOCK construct.  */
+  for (stack = cs_base; stack; stack = stack->prev)
+    {
+      if (stack->current->op == EXEC_BLOCK) saw_block = true;
+      if (saw_block && stack->current->op == EXEC_DO_CONCURRENT)
+   {
+     gfc_error ("Reference to impure function at %L inside a "
+            "DO CONCURRENT", &e->where);
+     return false;
+   }
+    }
+
   if (!gfc_pure_function (e, &name) && name)
     {
       if (forall_flag)



I see it was fixed very quickly: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/7d92901c878c6c00ada7f9cee8825f03ad4722f1

Yes, it was fixed.  But, the patch forgot to deal with an impure subroutine.  That's in the queue.

Patch for an impure subroutine was committed today.  In the future, if you suspect a bug in gfortran, please post to fortran@gcc.gnu.org.  I may not see a post in stackoverflow or be motivated enough to report for you.
